# Qt change background color when QTreeWidgetItem is checked

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a QTreeWidget where each item can have a state of hiden (which si different from disabled) or shown. to implement it I have decided to make each one of the QTreeWidgetItems checkable and now I want via QSS to change the background colour of the item.

The QTreeWidget seems to be behaving properly, each entry has a checkbox.The code to do so is this one:

```
    root = new QTreeWidgetItem(this->sceneTree);
    root->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled);
    root->setText(0, name);

    if (isEnabled)
        root->setCheckState(0, Qt::Checked);
    else
        root->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked);
```

I know I can change the background of QTreeWidgetItems with the following QSS:

```
QTreeView::item{
    background: red;
}
```

To my understanding, if I just want to change it while it is checked I should use:

```
QTreeView::item:checked {
    background: red;
}
```

But this is not working. I want to know if the problem is because I am understanding the workings of QSS wrong or the problem is somewhere else in my code. Thanks.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**:

This is not the answer to the question but how I have decide to solve the problem. As far as I know there is no way to use qss to get this behaviour so I am using the signal itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*, int) with a slot that contains the following code:

```
    if(item->checkState(col) == Qt::Checked)
        item->setForeground(0, QBrush(QColor("#4C4C4C")));
```

Comment: try item checked signal ? item checked stylesheet is not working

Comment: In the end I am using itemChanged and updating the foregroundColor each time